# PHP5.6.1 Mcrypt on Mac MAMP3.5

Tags: php, git, mcrypt

i am using git releases on my Mac
i using MAMP Pro 3.5 and installed composer
but when i try to "composer", show me error is:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mcrypt extension.
```

my PHP version is 5.6.10.how to fix it.